# PHP thinks date.timezone isn't set

Tags: php, php5, timezone

For some reason, even though I've uncommented the line in php.ini and properly set the value to `date.timezone = America/New_York`, php refuses to acknowledge it. When I open up phpinfo.php it says

> Warning: phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
>   settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the
>   date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those
>   methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

I've triple checked that it is referencing the correct php.ini file. On the [timezones page](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), it mentions a timezonesdb that can be downloaded. Do I have to install that because PHP doesn't come with built in timezones? That doesn't seem right.

Edit: I am using Apache2 and PHP that comes bundled with Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Usually when i have this problem it is because the php.ini that ships with oracle linux is incorrect and I **THINK** has a **space** instead of an **underscore** between `new` and `york`... not sure what is wrong here though.

Comment: Did you restart Apache?

Comment: I did restart Apache, but I just solved it. For some reason there was a weird summation symbol before [PHP] on the first line of the file. I figured it was supposed to be there because it was in php.ini.default, but it works fine after removing it.

Comment: Thanks for posting an update. May I suggest posting this as an answer to your own question in case others are having the same issue.

Comment: Probably a BOM. Be careful with your text editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason there was a weird summation symbol before [PHP] on the first line of the file. It works fine after removing it.